# Are there any standard methods to solve a linear objective with nonconvex constraints?

Tags: optimization

I see that [nonlinear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming#The_general_non-linear_optimization_problem_.28NLP.29) entails nonlinear objectives with convex or linear constraints. Is there any theory/method to solve linear objective with nonconvex constraints and some convex constraints?

Comment: Note that **every** optimization problem can be cast as a linear objective with non-linear constraints.

Comment: So, you mean I could retrace the linear objective to something else and change the constraints to convex or linear ones?

Comment: No, what I meant was that if there was a significant advantage to dealing with linear objectives and non-convex constraints, then I suspect a related body of optimization would have arisen by now. Many years ago (in the context of $\max$ functions) I looked at something similar (over a small range of numerical optimizations) with no clear advantage/disadvantage. Don't think of the comment as definitive in any way!

Comment: Oh, alright. That's a bummer. I felt like there was a standard approach to doing it.